# SQL Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm breaking my head over this one. I keep getting the error. I followed the resolutions on the other questions but nothing works for me. I really hope someone can correct me here.

All I want is to get the data out of a view

```
SELECT Table_view.Information
FROM Table_View
```

but I keep getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

I tried the following:

```
SELECT Table_View.Information
FROM Table_View
WHERE Table_View.Information NOT LIKE '%,%'

SELECT Table_View.Information
CASE WHEN CAST(Table_View.Information AS INT) = 1 THEN 'space' 
ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, Table_View.Information) END
FROM Table_View

SELECT CAST (REPLACE(REPLACE(Table_View.Information, ' ,', ' '),'/', '') AS VARCHAR)
FROM Table_View

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, REPLACE(REPLACE(Table_View.Information, ' ,', ' '),'/', ''))
FROM Table_View

SELECT Table_View.Information
CASE 
WHEN Table_View.Information NOT LIKE '%,%' THEN CAST(Table_View.Information AS VARCHAR)
END 

FROM Table_View
```

None of the above helps me resolve the issue. Any suggestions? I tried cast, convert, case, replace..

Comment: Obviously, the problem is inside the view and you won't be able to fix it (under most circumstances) with your `select` query.  You need to fix the *view* definition.

Comment: How does your view look like?

Comment: I think thats what needs to be done Gordon, I was hoping I could get some work around :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
WHERE Table_View.Information NOT LIKE '%,%'
```

The above code implies that Information is a character column, as it would be impossible to convert a comma into a number.

```html
CASE WHEN CAST(Table_View.Information AS INT) = 1 THEN 'space'
```

There error is here, as CAST does not provide a return value such that it can be compared to the number 1, and if the value contains a comma then any attempt to convert to an int would result in a type conversion error.

Try using `ISNUMERIC()` or `TRY_CAST()` in place of where you have CAST.

Comment: Thank You Jim, I tried ISNUMERIC() too. and we are using an older version of SQL so a bit stuck

Comment: Please tell us the SQL version we're talking about, as that is needed info to answer this question.  Thanks.

Comment: 2005 :).. We're old school

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you should use `try_convert()` or `try_cast()` if 2012+.  Rather than throwing an error, a NULL will be returned if the conversion fails.

That said, convert(money,...) tends to be a little more forgiving

**Example**

```
Declare @Table table (SomeCol varchar(50))  
Insert Into @Table values 
 ('$25.25')
,('-  252,525.25')

Select AsMoney = convert(money,SomeCol)  -- int would fail
 From  @Table
```

**Returns**

```
AsMoney
25.25
-252525.25
```

Comment: I really wish I could use TRY_CAST or TRY_CONVERT but we are using an older version of SQL

Comment: @EricDavid I suspected as much :(   However, give convert(money,...) a shot.  If it works without throwing an error, you can easily convert the results to an INT.